# how to handle recursion returning True and False along the calling stack

Tags: python

Rookie in python here. For recursion, always confused regarding how to handle return bool values. Such as:

```
def search (list, key):
    if list is empty:
        return False
    if key == first item in list:
        return True
    return search (list with first element removed, key)
```

There will be True and False returned as the call stack goes deep. How to handle such recursions?

Comment: Your pseudocode looks fine. What aspect of this situation do you not know how to handle?

Comment: You can return 0 if you need, since it looks like you're counting the occurrences in a nested list? I don't see this code having any issues.

Answer (score 3):

The names of the boolean constants are `True` and `False` (capitalization sensitive). Otherwise, you seem to have the idea on how to pass the values back up the call stack (I can't evaluate the pseudocode, but that wasn't your question).